# Seeking simple workflow set-up for Clojure/boot

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

How do you set up *boot* so that: (a) all source files are in the current directory, (b) unit tests run every time a source file is changed, (c) the REPL refreshes definitions when source files containing them change?

Specifically:

- What goes in `build.boot`?
- What's the shell command to start the REPL? And/or what command in the REPL starts the watching of unit tests?
- What other conventional set-up do I need to do?

I've read through a lot of documentation on [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot), [boot-test](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/boot-test), [boot-quick-test](https://github.com/brendanyounger/boot-quick-test), [REPL reloading in boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Repl-reloading), and [boot-refresh](https://github.com/samestep/boot-refresh), but I haven't been able to get much to work. The documentation I've found so far seems to provide tidbits and hints but not what's needed to put these things together.

A simple example of an appropriate `build.boot` (and whatever else) would be especially helpful.

---

So far, this is what I have that (sort of) works.

```
(set-env!
  :dependencies '[
    [adzerk/boot-test "1.1.2" :scope "test"]
    [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]]
  :source-paths #{"."})

(require '[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :as repl :refer [refresh]])
(apply repl/set-refresh-dirs (get-env :directories))
```

Plus one file in the current directory, `sample.clj`:

```
(ns sample
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(defn myfunc [] "this string")

(deftest test-myfunc
  (is (= "this string" (myfunc))))
```

This gets *boot* to find source files in the current directory, and it enables me to manually reload changes in `sample.clj` by typing `(refresh)` in the REPL. `(boot (test))` used to manually run the unit tests in a `.clj` file, but it failed when I tried it just now, with the error "Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/test".

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

[Due to how Boot handles watching and notifying about file changes you cannot use `clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh` directly.](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Repl-reloading)

You can use a wrapper for it - samestep/boot-refresh:

```
(set-env!
 :dependencies '[[adzerk/boot-test "1.1.2" :scope "test"]
                 [samestep/boot-refresh "0.1.0" :scope "test"]]
 :source-paths #{"."})

(require '[samestep.boot-refresh :refer [refresh]]
         '[adzerk.boot-test :refer :all])
```

Now you can start REPL server which will reload on file changes:

`boot repl -s watch refresh`

And connect to it either from your IDE (e.g. CIDER or Cursive) or via:

`boot repl -c`

and whenever there are changes in your source files detected, appropriate namespaces will be reloaded and available in your client REPL session.

You can also start `boot watch test` in another terminal to get auto-test behaviour.

And finally your issue with `(boot (test))` giving *Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/test* was caused because you didn't required `adzerk.boot-test` which contains a `test` task which you wanted to call. It looks that there might be `clojure.test/test` available which was called instead.

Comment: Thanks!! I am starting to be productive again. I didn't know about the trick of starting two REPL processes. Still one snag: when I add a new `defn` to a source file, the `repl -s` process reloads it but the `repl -c` process doesn't see it. That is, if I try to call the new function at the REPL client command line, it gives me "Unable to resolve symbol". Changes to an already existing function's definition do show up in the `repl -c` process, though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it might be the issue with how `require` with `:refer` and/or `:as` work internally. I get the same issues but calling new symbols with a full ns works for me.

Comment: What command calls new symbols with a full ns? (I'm not sure what "call new symbols" means.)

Comment: Never mind, I got it: `(sample/newfunc)` using the `sample` namespace above. Unit tests work without the fully qualified function name, so I'm able to write code. It would be nice to solve this refresh problem, but it's relatively minor.

Comment: Yes, I should have written "calling vars with their namespaced symbols". I guess the cause might be that `clojure.tools.namespace.repl/refresh` knows nothing about your REPL user ns as it is not loaded from a file watched by its internals.